# How to separate GraphQL schema and resolver files using Apollo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have this simple GraphQL Apollo server working when it's all within a single file, but I am having trouble getting it to work when "modularizing" the schema and resolvers to their own files.

`/index.js`

```
require('dotenv').config()
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } = require('apollo-server')

const { Query } = require('./resolvers/Query')

// database connection
MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_URL, {
  poolSize: 25,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  wtimeout: 2500
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB.', error.stack)
  process.exit(1)
}).then(async client => {
  console.log(`Connected to database: ${process.env.DB_NAME}`)

  const dbConnection = client.db(process.env.DB_NAME)

  const resolvers = {
    Query
  }

  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: './schema.graphql',
    resolvers
  })

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema: schema
  })

  server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
    console.log(`Server ready at ${url}.`)
  })
})
```

`/schema.graphql`

```
type CourseType {
  _id: String!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  courseType(_id: String): CourseType
  courseTypes: [CourseType]!
}
```

`/resolvers/Query.js`

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb')

const courseTypesCollection = dbConnection.collection(process.env.DB_COLLECTION_COURSE_TYPES)

const Query = {
  courseType: async (root, { _id }) => {
    return courseTypesCollection.findOne(ObjectId(_id))
  },
  courseTypes: async () => {
    return courseTypesCollection.find({}).toArray()
  }
}

module.exports = {
  Query
}
```

When I try to run the `index.js` file, I get the error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character "."`. This seems like I'm not properly loading/using the schema file. I would like to have this working without adding more libraries, if `apollo-server` can handle this on it's own.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Your second question is not related to the first and should be posted separately.

Comment: @TalZ my apologies, second question removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`makeExecutableSchema` expects `typeDefs` to be either a string of the type definitions, a `DocumentNode` object representing the type definitions parsed into AST, an array of either of the former will be merged together. Here it seems you are passing a file path to `typeDefs` instead of the content of the file.

You could change the `/schema.graphql` file to a simple code file like this for example:

```
const schema = `
  type CourseType {
    _id: String!
    name: String!
  }

  type Query {
    courseType(_id: String): CourseType
    courseTypes: [CourseType]!
  }
`
module.exports = schema
```

then load it to typedef

```
  const graphQLSchema = require('./schema.graphql')
  //...

  const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: graphQLSchema,
    resolvers
  })
```

You could load multiple schemas this way if you pass an array to `typeDefs`

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know `typeDefs` was just looking for a string. Question: Is there a method from `apollo-server` that can parse a `.graphql` file for the schema, rather than having to encapsulate the  `schema.graphql` as a string?

Comment: I don't know if there is a built in method, but you can easily do that yourself using `fs.readFile(...)`